# Development Console in Google App Engine with Struts 2

Tags: google-app-engine, struts2

I tried Struts 2 in Google App Engine following example from http://www.mkyong.com/google-app-engine/google-app-engine-struts-2-example

It works perfectly but I can't accessed Development Console which is supposed to be accessed in http://localhost:8888/_ah/admin

Is it about the filter? How to fixed it?

Below is the content of web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    version="2.5">
    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.mkyong.listener.Struts2ListenerOnGAE</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by appending the code below to struts.xml

```
<constant name="struts.action.excludePattern" value="/_ah/admin"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the `<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>` maps everything to Struts filter.

Comment: what should be the work-around to access GAE Development Console?